# System out of GPU memory

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

Since I got my new GPU this error comes up from time to time when rendering a small (100 frame) animation.

At the top of the renderview (F12) it says "System out of GPU memory". When I restart blender and try again it's working.

What is the reason for this? Is blender filling my VRAM with (useless) stuff for whatever reason?

The GPU is a RTX 3080 with 10GB and my old card was a 1060 with 6 GB and I never had this problem, same scene, same animation and besides the GPU same PC.

After tweaking some stuff and trying to render the exact same scene (after the restart) it says again "System is out of GPU memory". Is blender not clearing it correctly after the render is done?
When I check the VRAM it's at 6 GB (out of 10GB)

Comment: This sounds like a driver compatibility problem, where either blender OR the drivers could be out of date on protocol.